# Generate price from a list with Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few variables:

```
var test1 = 1500;
var test2 = 500;
var test3 = 3000;
var test4 = 20000;
```

And I have an another variable like this:

```
var list = 'test3,test1';
```

This is not fixed obviously, so that can be `'test4,test1,test2'` etc..

Now, I need a price variable. `test3+test1 = 4500`

```
var price = '4500';
```

But I don't have any idea how to do that. Here is what I have so far:

```
var names = [];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    names.push(this.name);
});
var list = names.join(',');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ...what are you trying to do?

Comment: What's the relationship between the checkboxes and the test variables?  Is it the case where you have a list of checkboxes and each one has text which is the price and you need to total them? please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change your variables into a proper object:

```
var prices = {
    "test1": 1500,
    "test2": 500,
    "test3": 3000,
    "test4": 20000
}
```

Now you can add like so:

```
var price = 0;
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    price += prices[this.name];
});
// The price variable now contains the sum
```

Comment: This is what I would guess he's doing

Answer (score 1):

Given your method, you can `join` the names with `' + '` instead of `','` and then just `eval` the result (see [example](http://support.engagesoftware.com/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?ID=954&PROJID=3)).

However, it would be better to store the values in a way that doesn't require using `eval`, such as storing them as the `value` of the checkboxes, or using a mapping between checkbox names and values (as with @[cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259318/generate-price-from-a-list-with-javascript-variables/4259357#4259357)'s answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your "test" prices should be in an array `test[1] = 1500; test[2] = 500;` etc..

Then without joining your array into a string,

```
price = 0; 
for (i in list) { // assuming list is array of {3,1} not {test3,test1}
    price += test[list[i]];
}
```